# How can I check App quit in the facebook instant games?

Tags: javascript, facebook, fig

I want to call my custom callback when player out of the game. In the docs I found only `FBInstant.quit();` method, but I need an exit event. Does Facebook have this feature?

Answer (score 0):

There are no specific SDK events for this. You may be able to intercept the `unload` event as described here: [Detect browser or tab closing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888902/detect-browser-or-tab-closing)